# Selecting the largest value in array

Tags: javascript

```
var strings = [ '123-456-7777', '223-456-7777', '123-456-7777' ];
var ints = strings.map(el => el.replace(/-/g, '').split('').reduce((sum, a) => sum + +a, 0));
console.log(ints);

if( ints[0] > ints[1] && ints[0] > ints[2]){
    console.log(strings[0]);
    console.log(ints[0]);
}else if (ints[1] > ints[0] && ints[1] > ints[2]) {
    console.log(strings[1]);
    console.log(ints[1]); 
}else{
    console.log(strings[2]);
    console.log(ints[2]);
};
```

I have a few questions.

1. Can I replace this If statement with a switch statement?
2. I am trying to make the function that prints out the array which has has the largest sum. What other way is there to make this look better?

Comment: I suggest you google for "javascript maximum".

Comment: What about if two members sum to the same value, which one should be returned? Or both?

Answer (score 0):

`Math.max.apply(Math, ints)` gives you the max value. Along with `indexOf` you can get the index of the max value.

```
var strings = [ '123-456-7777', '223-456-7777', '123-456-7777' ];
var ints = strings.map(el => el.replace(/-/g, '').split('').reduce((sum, a) => sum + +a, 0));

console.log(ints);
var max = Math.max.apply(Math, ints);
console.log(strings[ints.indexOf(max)], max); //223-456-7777, 50
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `switch` or `if...else`. You can use `Math.max` and pass the array to it calling it using `apply`.

1. Remove the hyphens from the array elements
2. Get the individual digit
3. Get summation of individual digits in the array
4. Get the maximum number from the array.

**Code:**

```
Math.max.apply(Math, arr.map(str => str.match(/\d/g).reduce((sum, num) => sum + +num, 0)));
```

```js
var arr = ['123-456-7777', '223-456-7777', '123-456-7777'];
var max = Math.max.apply(Math, arr.map(str => str.match(/\d/g).reduce((sum, num) => sum + +num, 0)));

console.log(max);
document.write(max);
```

**Code Explanation:**

`str.match(/\d/g).reduce((sum, num) => sum + +num, 0))` will give the summation of individual digits in the main array elements.

`arr.map` will update the element of each array to the returned value i.e. the summation of individual digits.

`Math.max.apply(Math, array)` will call the `Math.max` function and pass the elements of array as individual parameters.

Equivalent code in ES5:

```
var arr = ['123-456-7777', '223-456-7777', '123-456-7777'];
var max = Math.max.apply(Math, arr.map(function (str) {
    return str.match(/\d/g).reduce(function (sum, num) {
        return sum + +num;
    }, 0)
}));
console.log(max);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always sort the array and take the max element:

```
strings.map(function(e){ return e.split('-').reduce(function(a,b){return +a + +b}) }).sort(function(a,b){return b-a})[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `for` loop, `while` loop , `delete` , `Array.prototype.sort()`

```js
var strings = ['123-456-7777', '223-456-7777', '123-456-7777'];

for (var i = 0, len = strings.length, res = Array(len).fill(0); i < len; i++) {
  var j = strings[i].length, n = -1;
  while (--j > n) {
    if (!isNaN(strings[i][j])) {
      res[i] += +strings[i][j]
    }
  };
  if (res[i - 1] && res[i] > res[i - 1]) {
    delete res[i - 1]
  } else {
    if (res[i] < res[i - 1]) {
      delete res[i];
      res.sort(Boolean)
    }
  };
};

document.body.textContent = res.join(" ")
```